# Routing error while using partial form in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

does anyone know how to use a form partial to create and update data about an object? My update method seems to work, but I can't create a new object. Every time I clink on the 'Add new ad' I get this error:[ActionController:Routing Error in Classified#new    No route matches {:controller=>classified}].  Here is the code for the partial form: The error points to the first line:

```
<%= form_for(@classified) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :price %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :price %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :location %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :location %>
  </p>
  <%= f.label :description %><br/>
  <%= f.text_area :description %>
  <%= f.label :email %><br/>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'Back', {:action => 'list'} %>
```

Here are my methods for new, edit and update in the Classified controller class:

```
def new
  @classified=Classified.new
end
```

Here is the 'def create' method:

```
def create
  @classified = Classified.new(params[:classified])
  if @classified.save
    redirect_to :action => 'list'
  else
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end
```

I suspect the problem is in my config/routes.rb. I already have this line:

```
resources :classified
```

I have also put:

```
root :to => "Classified#list"
root :to => "Classified#new"
root :to => "Classified#show"
root :to => "Classified#edit"
root :to => "Classified#form
```

Could the problem be with the routes.rb file. And how comes it works with the update method and not the new method?  Please help. I have tried all possible tricks to no avail. I will be so glad. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I would like to know the result of your `rake routes`, because you use the singular for your controller classified.

Could it be `classifieds`, with the S in all your routes? I'm not that sure because `resources: classified` I guess came from the scaffold and so it should be good, then you miss a `"' on your last line but this could be a typo.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend having a plural name for the resource, as that is the norm for most resources:

```
resources :classifieds
```

You will also need to change your controller name and class name to `classifieds_controller` and `ClassifiedsController`

Also, your named routes should be lowercase (although you should get rid of these routes altogether):

```
root :to => "classifieds#list"
```

Get rid of the `root` routes.  The `resources` line will create all the routes you need.  And you are only supposed to have one root route in `routes.rb` and that should point to your home page controller#action.

If you have an action for form, then you don't need that either.. just mentioning this because you created a route for "Classified#form".  Controller actions are not necessary for partials.

Your new and create methods and the form look ok at first glance.  Try reworking your routes first and if you are still having problems, run `rake routes` from the command line and post the output in your question and leave me a comment on this answer and I will see if I can help you figure it out.

Read this first:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: that was there for three hours with nobody paying attention and we went editing and answering it at the same time... :)

Comment: I saw a new answer was posted when I was finishing up this answer.  I figured I would hit submit since I already put some time into it ;-)